# Java Serialized Class Objects with Java Servlets

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, serialization

I currently have a class project where I need to deploy a simple banking web application on Tomcat. Upon opening up the application, we should be brought to an HTML file that contains a form for users to submit a username OR for them to create a new account. This must be done by using Java servlets where the mapping is done in a web.xml.

The part where I am having trouble with is incorporating serializable objects. In my case, the serializable object class is Accounts. In the servlets, I need to know how to manipulate them (create, store, delete, and retrieve).

Here is the Account.java that I'm referencing. 
[Account.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m94dR.png)

```
//Class from which objects will be created 
//and then passed as arguments.

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Account implements Serializable
{
        private int acctNum;
        private String surname;
        private String firstNames;
        private double balance;

        public Account(int acctNo, String sname, String fnames, double bal)
        {
                acctNum = acctNo;
                surname = sname;
                firstNames = fnames;
                balance = bal;
        }

        public int getAcctNum()
        {
                return acctNum;
        }

        public String getName()
        {
                return (firstNames + " " + surname);
        }

        public double getBalance()
        {
                return balance;
        }

        public double withdraw(double amount)
        {
                if (amount <= balance)
                        return amount;
                else
                        return 0;
        }

        public void deposit(double amount)
        {
                if (amount > 0)
                        balance += amount;
        }
}
```

And here is an example of a Java servlet I would be using.
[FirstServlet.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6QdJ.png)

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class FirstServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                        HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException,ServletException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/HTML");

        String user = request.getParameter("usrname");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        /*
        out.println("<HTML>");
        out.println("<HEAD>");
        out.println("<TITLE>Simple Servlet</TITLE>");
        out.println("</HEAD>");
        out.println("<BODY>");
        out.println("<BR><BR><BR>");
        out.println("<CENTER><H1> A Simple Servlet </H1></CENTER>");
        out.println("</BODY>");
        out.println("</HTML>");
        */
        out.print("<html><head><title>Simple Servlet</title></head><body><br><br><br><CENTER><H1> A Simple Servlet </H1><br><br>Username: "+ user +"</CENTER></body></html>");
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, be a more specific about your problem. What error are you getting? What you have tried so far? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** If you just want to submit data to the servlet you can do it as described below. Note that this is a one way communication because HTML can just submit requests but will not be able to parse or even receive any results back. That's why you need to either use Javascript / jQuery to send and retrieve requests or change from using HTML to using JSP which can work with servlets.

HTML

```
<form method="post or get" action="/web_context/servlet_mapping">
    <!-- inputs and buttons -->
</form>
```

Servlet

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3247638875724522260L;

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // use these to get the form inputs
        request.getParameterMap();
        request.getParameter("some_parameter");

        // process parameters

        // create any objects

        // perform actions on object
    }

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // same thing here
    }
}
```

**original answer below**

One approach for this case is to have your form in the HTML file, and on submission of forms or on other user actions send a Post or Get (depending on action) request using jQuery to the backend servlet.

The servlet receives all data that is sent to it in the HttpServletRequest object, so the data that is sent using jQuery can be read and processed.

To help marshal the data back and forth, I suggest you use the [Gson library](https://github.com/google/gson) in the backend and send all data in JSON format. This will allow you to serialize and deserialize your objects very easily.

You can have one servlet that takes in data and an action type and routes the data to a particular action. Or you can have a servlet for each action.

You didn't mention a database, but you will need that too.

Comment: For our project, we're not using any database. It's all about abstracting a webserver where we add state by using servlets and cookies. And I prefer not to bring in any other language. This is a school project. We have an initial HTML file where servlets are mapped in a web.xml. All servlets are .java files. Anything else would be out of scope.

Comment: @lli I guess in that case your only option is to submit the form to the servlet and then parse all the inputs and create objects manually.

Comment: @lli I've updated my answer to have an example, but please read the note on the communication between HTML and servlets.

Comment: thanks for the update. I understand the interaction between the HTML and servlets, but the part I struggle with is mainly creating a java serializable object (Account.java above) and using it within my servlet code. I want to be able to take in the form input and create an account and display all of the accounts that I have.

Comment: Have you tried to implement the example I posted? And like i said HTML and Java is a one way street, so "display all of the accounts" is not going to work unless you use JSP pages or Javascript requests